# How to compare a sound input with a pre-determined sound?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

Elaborate:

Suppose I play a G on my guitar and my sound card has taken an input. How to make my computer recognize that it is G? (No constraints on programming language, though prefer Python or C)( Links to articles or certain ideas would help. No code snippets)

Comment: Comparing against a pre-determined sound is not how pitch recognition is done.  Poor title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the Goertzel filter nor an FFT are good musical pitch estimators.  The FFT is a frequency estimator, and peak spectral frequency is different from psycho-acoustic pitch (due to perceptual oddities and the physics of actual musical instruments, such as missing or weak fundamentals).

Search on stackoverflow for musical pitch estimation algorithms.  There are a bunch.

Comment: From your experience, which algorithm is the best at approximating the very psycho-acoustic pitch you mention?

Comment: You might want to ask that as another better question.  It probably depends on the details of your requirements and constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Fast Fourier Transformation. Here's some code : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/FftGuitarTuner.aspx

Comment: FFT based frequency estimators make horrible guitar tuners.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check for a few frequencies, the [Goertzel algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) might be simpler to implement. (And faster at runtime)